# Replace data in a dataframe using values from another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to replace values in dataframe df1 using data from another (dataframe df2) through column 'name'.
Note that name is not unique on df1 (but it is on df2)

## df1

| id | country | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | romania | john | 100 |
| 2 | russia | emma | 200 |
| 3 | usa | mark | 400 |
| 4 | china | emma | 300 |
| 5 | portugal | nick | 200 |

## df2

| id | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | emma | 2 |
| 2 | mark | 3 |

## desidered result

| id | country | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | romania | john | 100 |
| 2 | russia | emma | 2 |
| 3 | usa | mark | 3 |
| 4 | china | emma | 2 |
| 5 | portugal | nick | 200 |

How can I do this using python (panda library)?

Answer (score 1):

First merges the two dataframes on the '`name`' column.

Replaces the '`value`' column with the new values where available

Filling in with the original values where there are no new values.

Finally, drops the additional columns added during the merge.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'country': ['romania', 'russia', 'usa', 'china', 'portugal'],
    'name': ['john', 'emma', 'mark', 'emma', 'nick'],
    'value': [100, 200, 400, 300, 200]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2],
    'name': ['emma', 'mark'],
    'value': [2, 3]
})

merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='left', suffixes=('_original', '_new'))

merged_df['value'] = merged_df['value_new'].fillna(merged_df['value_original'])

# Drop the additional columns from the merge
merged_df.drop(['id_new', 'value_new'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(merged_df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   id_original   country  name  value_original  value
0            1   romania  john             100  100.0
1            2    russia  emma             200    2.0
2            3       usa  mark             400    3.0
3            4     china  emma             300    2.0
4            5  portugal  nick             200  200.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

country ={
    'romania': ['john' , 100] ,
    'russia' : ['emma', 200] ,
    'usa'    : ['mark', 400] ,
    'china'  : ['emma', 300] ,
    'portugal': ['nick', 200] ,
}

df_country = pd.DataFrame(country, index = ['name', 'value'])

print(df_country)

'''The current output:
      romania russia   usa china portugal
name     john   emma  mark  emma     nick
value     100    200   400   300      200
'''

df_country.loc['value', df_country.loc['name'] == 'emma'] = 2
df_country.loc['value', df_country.loc['name'] == 'mark'] = 3

print(df_country)

'''The new output:
      romania russia   usa china portugal
name     john   emma  mark  emma     nick
value     100      2     3     2      200
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the above by
using the pd.merge function

```
#create dataframes with your data
data1 = [data]
data2 = [data]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns='column1', 'column2')
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3')

df_3 = pd.merge(df1, df_2, on='id', how='inner')
```

df_3 should give you the desired result, you can modify the how to change how the empty data is merged, (how='outer' or how='inner' theres also how='left' and 'right')